# Event handlers in book "Under the hood of .NET memory management"

Tags: .net, memory-management, event-handling

I'm reading the book `Under the hood of .NET memory management` (published by Red-Gate). You can find a [pdf version on their website](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/wp-content/uploads/RedGateBooks/ChrisFarrell/Under_the_Hood_of_NET_Management.pdf).

I thought I understood event handlers with respect to the references that are created between publishers and subscribers, but the authors' explanation of event handlers in Chapter 5 "Application-specific problems" (under the title "Windows Presentation Foundation") confuses me.

On pages 160-161 they describe a UI design that uses a master/detail relationship. I quote (numbers between square brackets are mine, in order to create references for my questions, pun not so much intended):

> You may have a grid with a list
>   of master records, and when you click on a record from the master grid, a new window
>   opens with the details associated with that master record. If the master window wires up
>   events in the detail window [1], then the detail window cannot be garbage collected until the
>   event handlers in the master window release their references to the detail window [2]. In this
>   case, the detail window will be the listener and the master window is the source [3]. In most
>   cases, the master window will outlive the details window, but if the event handlers are
>   not handled properly, then the detail window cannot be garbage collected as long as the
>   master window is alive.

```
Detail.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(Master.SomeEvent_Handler); [4]
```

[1] This is very unclear terminology. Who "wires up" who? From this alone, I cannot determine who's the listener and who's the subscriber (I can only suppose...). The next sentence [3] seemingly answers this very question by saying that the master is the source and the detail is the listener, but only after having introduced confusion by stating the exact opposite in [2] (because imo the event *handlers* are *not* in the master window).

The code example [4] also doesn't correspond with what is said in [3] (but corresponds with [2]). If the master window is the source, then it should be:

```
Master.SomeEvent += new EventHandler(Detail.SomeEvent_Handler); [5]
```

Right?

Apart from all this confusion, I understand event handlers as follows. If `Master` has events, to which `Detail` subscribes (as in [5]), then `Master` has a refence to `Detail` (because a reference to an instance delete creates a reference to the instance, `Detail` in this case). So, as long as `Master` lives, `Detail` will also be held in memory, unless the event handler is decoupled from the event.

Are my critique of the book and my own understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is never very obvious from the C# syntax sugar.  A delegate constructor takes *two* arguments under the hood.  The obvious one is the event handler method.  The non-obvious one is the object whose handler method is going to be called.  Non-obvious because you never type it in the code.  It is `this`.  C# does not even allow you to specify it, other languages do.

So the Master object now how a reference to the Detail object, necessary to properly invoke the event handler method.

So as long as the Master object is alive, the Detail object is not going to get collected.  Unless you explicitly unsubscribe the event again or use the WPF weak event pattern.  Or, ideally, design the code so the Master and the Detail objects die at the same time.  They gave you an example where that is not easy to do.

There are other ways to do it that don't use events.  You could declare an IDetail interface with methods that represent the event you'd want to raise.  And give the Master class an AddDetail(IDetail) and RemoveDetail(IDetail) method.  Now the memory management is crystal-clear and it becomes a lot more obvious when you forget to call RemoveDetail().  The WPF designers however heavily favored using events instead, they had to come up with the weak event pattern to avoid the leaks in their own object model.

Comment: What's the significance of the non-obvious `this` parameter? Does it set context (like in javascript? (pardon the heresy))? Could you point me to some documentation or book(s)? I would like to read more on this.

Comment: Nothing particularly deep.  The event is calling an instance method, it needs an object reference.  The delegate stores it.  Note the Delegate.Target property.  It just is not very easy to see how it gets a value.